App is crashing on iPhone immediately installing from Xcode and it is opening app settings. The project is build on flutter SDK
App is crashing on iPhone immediately installing from Xcode.
The project is build on flutter SDK.
I have done some setup on native iOS side implemented Firebase dependency in Podfile, I have also removed the Debug/GoogleService-Info and Release/GoogleService-Info folders beacause they were not added by xcode and have added GoogleService-Info-uat & GoogleService-Info-prod directly inside the Runner folder. 
I have checked the firebase everything is working checked with sending notification they are also coming but crash is there.
here are the logs :::::
>  Application launched on the device. Waiting for Dart VM Service url.
>   [+2112 ms] Received logs from ios-deploy.
>  [   +8 ms] (lldb) 2024-11-28 22:15:25.353193+0530 Rnner[43988:2285134] >[PreviewsAgentExecutorLibrary] Looking up debug dylib relative path
>     [   +1 ms] [PreviewsAgentExecutorLibrary] Found debug dylib relative path string `Runner.debug.dylib`
>     [        ] [PreviewsAgentExecutorLibrary] Looking up debug dylib entry point name
>     [        ] [PreviewsAgentExecutorLibrary] No debug dylib entry point name defined.
>     [        ] [PreviewsAgentExecutorLibrary] Looking up debug dylib install name
>     [        ] [PreviewsAgentExecutorLibrary] Found debug dylib install name string `@rpath/Runner.debug.dylib`
>     [        ] [PreviewsAgentExecutorLibrary] Looking for Previews JIT link entry point.
>     [        ] [PreviewsAgentExecutorLibrary] No Previews JIT entry point found.
>     [        ] [PreviewsAgentExecutorLibrary] Gave PreviewsInjection a chance to run and it returned, continuing with debug dylib.
>     [        ] [PreviewsAgentExecutorLibrary] Looking for main entry point.
>     [   +1 ms] [PreviewsAgentExecutorLibrary] Opening debug dylib with '@rpath/Runner.debug.dylib'
>     [        ] [PreviewsAgentExecutorLibrary] Debug dylib handle: 0x208bd51e0
>     [        ] [PreviewsAgentExecutorLibrary] No entry point found. Checking for alias.
>     [        ] [PreviewsAgentExecutorLibrary] Calling provided entry point.
>     [ +208 ms] [ERROR:flutter/shell/platform/darwin/graphics/FlutterDarwinContextMetalImpeller.mm(42)]
> Using the Impeller rendering backend.
>     [  +14 ms] [LIFE_CYCLE] didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
>     [  +97 ms] [Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 10.29.0
>     [  +16 ms] [INFO] Creating new FlutterEngine for task: acko_service_os_flutter_engine
>     [   +3 ms] [ERROR:flutter/shell/platform/darwin/graphics/FlutterDarwinContextMetalImpeller.mm(42)]
> Using the Impeller rendering backend.
>     [   +1 ms] FFmpegKitFlutterPlugin 0x282008120 created.
>     [        ] 10.29.0 - [FirebaseCore][I-COR000012] Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'.
>     [  +49 ms] VM Service URL on device: http://127.0.0.1:53862/0g-GbtOqDyQ=/
>     [   +6 ms] Attempting to forward device port 53862 to host port 52416
>     [        ] executing: /Users/******/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/usbmuxd/iproxy 52416:53862
> --udid 00008030-000E05000CC0402E --debug
>     [  +27 ms] [LIFE_CYCLE] applicationDidBecomeActive
>     [  +14 ms] [FIREBASE] device Token 32 bytes
>     [   +2 ms] [FIREBASE] FCM Token
>     Optional("fUfDjoyENElujws5vRtzZl:APA91bHJL7X7_J-e3ln8CCE6V1Dbq9SLQl3PawhC44XfBI7h8Yp-FrPOxGuvkjT0UjA2tNSYcC69PgN1a****************_1CU3KLdKREEz5CjBToAI")
>     [ +972 ms] Forwarded port ForwardedPort HOST:52416 to DEVICE:53862
>     [        ] Forwarded host port 52416 to device port 53862 for VM Service
>     [   +3 ms] Installing and launching... (completed in 37.3s)
>     [   +2 ms] Caching compiled dill
>     [ +133 ms] Connecting to service protocol: http://127.0.0.1:52416/0g-GbtOqDyQ=/
>     [  +74 ms] Launching a Dart Developer Service (DDS) instance at http://127.0.0.1:0, connecting to VM service at
> http://127.0.0.1:52416/0g-GbtOqDyQ=/.
>     [  +68 ms] DDS is listening at http://127.0.0.1:52422/paepT3qVSM0=/.
>     [  +31 ms] Successfully connected to service protocol: http://127.0.0.1:52416/0g-GbtOqDyQ=/
>     [  +16 ms] DevFS: Creating new filesystem on the device (null)
>     [   +9 ms] DevFS: Created new filesystem on the device
>     (file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C944A612-E05B-401F-ACB7-592E246438DC/tmp/central-service-os-appiCoXyZ/central-service-os-app/)
>     [        ] Updating assets
>     [ +226 ms] Manifest contained wildcard assets. Inserting missing file into build graph to force rerun. for more information see #56466.
>     [   +2 ms] Syncing files to device Geeks iPhone...
>     [   +1 ms] Compiling dart to kernel with 0 updated files
>     [        ] Processing bundle.
>     [        ] <- recompile package:service_os_flutter/main.dart a762fc7c-da8c-4e86-be5b-e7bed0c5a569
>     [        ] <- a762fc7c-da8c-4e86-be5b-e7bed0c5a569
>     [   +1 ms] Bundle processing done. 

